# Yii loses session after redirect

Tags: php, session, yii

I have yii project and in Chrome sessions is lost.
Example:
config in main.php

```
'session' => array(
            'class' => 'CDbHttpSession',
            'autoStart' => false,
            'connectionID' => 'db',
            'sessionTableName' => 'ph_YiiSession',
            'autoCreateSessionTable' => false    // for performance reasons
        ),
```

in start controller after login i write id user in session

```
Yii::app()->user->id = 100
```

after i redirect user

```
$this->redirect(array('student/index'), true);
```

but in index action i can't get data from session

```
echo Yii::app()->user->id;
```

give nothing. Please help, this problem crashed my brain already

Comment: what are you trying to do?? how is Yii::app()->user->id is related to session here??

Comment: pls post your identify code...

Comment: http://pastebin.com/bBV1J4XN

Comment: UserIdentity code needed... not login code.

Comment: Did you ever get this fixed ? I am experiencing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

You should try

```
'autoStart' => true,
```

Comment: may this helps you. http://php.refulz.com/configuring-session-in-yii-framework-cdbhttpsession/

Comment: not helping, i look at table ph_YiiSession and have 1 row, but in column `data` nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```
Yii::app()->user->id = 100
```

**First of all**
 You can't set the **Id** like this permanently that could work in different pages. Even if you will set Id in a page, Its data will be lost as soon as you move to next page and it will show its default value. So if you want to change the value that `Yii::app()->user->id` contains then you will have to override [getId()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUserIdentity#getId-detail) method.

**Second Thing**
 If you are trying to save the Id in the session then you should use `Yii::app()->session['_myId']=Yii::app()->user->id;`
and then you can get it like

```
echo Yii::app()->session['_myId'];
```

and remember `'autoStart' => TRUE,`

Comment: 1. i did it as example to show. 2. i did it already (use session['_myId']), not working, in db - nothing.

Comment: for example: in site controller i write Yii::app()->session['value'] = '12345'; After redirect to other controller: echo Yii::app()->session['value']; - nothing page, nothing in db

Answer (score 0):

**What you are doing wrong is definitely in the UserIdentity class**. The best method of setting and retrieving a session data from `Yii::app()->user->id`, is to override the `getId()` method in the UserIdentity class.

For example, lets say that you have a table named 'User' and it contains : id, username, password.

So, make the UserIdentity class something like this :

```
<?php

/**
 * UserIdentity represents the data needed to identity a user.
 * It contains the authentication method that checks if the provided
 * data can identity the user.
 */
class UserIdentity extends CUserIdentity
{

    private $_id;

    public function authenticate()
    {
        $user = User::model()->find('LOWER(username)=?',array(strtolower($this->username)));
        if($user===null){
            $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;

        }else if($user->password !== crypt($this->password,$user->password)){
            $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
        }
        else{
            $this->_id = $user->id;
            $this->username = $user->username;
            $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_NONE;
        }
        return $this->errorCode === self::ERROR_NONE;
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->_id;
    }
}
```

Once you do this, you should be able to use the Yii::app()->user->id and get the session id anywhere in your code.

Hope this helped.

P.S > I have also made a base app where all this is already done. You may check it out at : https://github.com/sankalpsingha/yii-base-app it might help you.

Comment: in process i find that file session store (i change from CDbHttpSession to CHttpSession), but data in them NOT. In this environment exists other application that use session and is alright. This magic for me.